# 14/3 to Power Two Switches

Tags: electrical, switch, light

This is the problem, I have 14/2 (source power)into one three way switch (living room), 14/3 from that switch to a light box in the ceiling (a light is supposed to go there - different switch).
14/3 from ceiling box, to 4-gang box in kitchen. This connects to a three way switch going to the lights in kitchen. There are additional wires coming from another box on the other side of the room that go to the lights in the kitchen.

How would I connect a light in the ceiling box to be controlled by a single pole switch that is in the kitchen. Diagram added (please pardon my lack of drawing skills
"x" is where wires are connected
[image]

[image: Goes to the ceiling box - Power source]
[image: 1A actually goes to 1]
[image: 1A comes from ceiling is 1B at ceiling - 1B goes to the lights]
[image: Final switch location wires go to the lights]

Comment: @david-w-reece Without knowing what's in the 4-gang box, your choices would be to leave it the way it is or eliminate one of the 3-way switches.

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of all boxes involved please?

Comment: Here are the pictures

Comment: The pictures are informative, but only so far as you've got 4 different boxes and countless wires here that you haven't identified.  We have no idea what any of this means.  The situation remains vague and the question is totally unclear.